# GPS Location in Chrome

Tags: gps, android, chrome

I am wanting to utilize a high accuracy GNSS position in a GIS data collection application optimized for Chrome running on my Android device. The problem is that the device doesn't have Google Play or Google Play services, which seems to restrict the ability for Chrome to receive the GPS data from the location manager.

Has anyone experienced this in the past? If so, is there any work around available so Chrome can get the GPS position from the location manager?